# hazelcast maploader listener

Tags: cluster-computing, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have a single member that has a MapStore/Loader that reads/writes to a database and also a client that adds an EntryAddedListener listener.

If the member is bounced, I see entry added listeners being fired, as the MapLoader reloads the data from database.

However this suggests to the client that new entries have been added, whereas in fact, they are only being "added" because of the node bootstrapping up.

Basically I don't want these listeners to be fired as a result of the MapLoader bootstrapping the map - they should only be fired afterwards.

How do I stop these MapLoader events firing off EntryAdded listeners?

Comment: Is there any code example that can help other users understand the problem?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do it. 
Loading an Entry using a MapLoader is basically adding an Entry to the Map.

What you could do is to add these listeners after the map has been loaded. 
If your loadingMode is set to EAGER it's easy to determine when the loading has finished completely.

In order to wait till the loading has finished you can invoke map.size() operation. When it finishes the map is fully-populated.

Comment: Thanks. Yes it has been set to eager from the member. Is it possible to determine if the map is fully loaded from the client itself though?

Comment: In order to wait till the loading has finished you can invoke map.size() operation. When it finishes the map is fully-populated.

Comment: So from a client perspective I would have to remove a listener on a client disconnection event callback, then wait for a client reconnect, but additionally invoke size() and only then re-add the listeners?

Comment: What I'm saying is that it's difficult to handle your use-case from a client. I'm not sure if a member will load the entries using-map loader if it is bounced. They should be actually migrated from other members that already hold that data. But when you start the app the listener will be fired definitely. As I understand your use-case you wouldn't like it to happen. It would be great if you could create a github issue for that so that we track it and maybe implement it in the future. Lastly, it would be great if you could accept my answer since it's accurate at the current state of the art.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to distinguish ADD and LOAD events starting from Hazelcast [v3.11](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/rn/index.html#3-11). This feature has been introduced as a part of [hazelcast-13181](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/pull/13181) issue.

Also you may want to check Java-docs for [EntryAddedListener](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/map/listener/EntryAddedListener.html) and [EntryLoadedListener](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/map/listener/EntryLoadedListener.html) for more details.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. You're not really answering the question here; you're just throwing a bunch of links up to external documentation.